# Yichud and shomer negiah - yehareg Val Yaavor?

Tags: halacha, martyr, yichud-seclusion, negia

Are Yichud and Shomer Negiah yehareg Val Yaavor from an orthodox perspective? I’ve read some things saying they are under the concept that they might lead to forbidden sexual relationships. I’m a bit confused by that because some sexual relationships aren’t even yehareg Val Yaavor so it seems weird that the thing trying to prevent it from happening would be more severe than the worse thing?

Comment: Relations with all arayos (niddah included which you can safely assume all single girls are) are יהרג ועל יעבור, which relationships are you thinking of?

Comment: True about niddah, I wasn’t thinking about that. Ignore that part then… just wondering if the things done to prevent possible relations are also yehareg Val Yaavor. Or I suppose if a single woman knew she wasn’t niddah… would it be yehareg Val Yaavor from her perspective for Yichud and shomer negiah with a man

Comment: There's much discussion about those questions, see https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php/%D7%90%D7%91%D7%99%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA for a short summary

Comment: Now I’m wondering why negiah and Yichud are permitted for immediate family when there’s tons of arayos there. Hopefully someone isn’t looking at their family that way but it’s confusing

Comment: That's the presumption. Mother/daughter less of an issue than a sister.

Comment: I just thought negiah and Yichud between a man and a woman applies even if they are totally not having any possibility of attraction. Sometimes Halacha sends me down rabbit holes of trying to understand the logic.